# Why we both have find function and index function in SAS?

Tags: indexing, sas, find

As the HELP document says:

> The FIND function and the INDEX function both search for substrings of characters in a character string. However, the INDEX function does not have the modifier nor the start-position arguments.

so why we have the both functions? Can't we just replace index() with find()?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Feature accretion is symptomatic of a software product that is 47 years old and maintains a high degree of backward compatibility.  Also, deprecated features are not documented, but may still function.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @Richard, the `find()` function was added to SAS after the `index()` function. This can be seen in the "What's New" details SAS provide [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/whatsnew/91x/lrdictwhatsnew900.htm).

If, as indicated elsewhere, you have trouble getting to the link, then perform a web search for "What's new in SAS 9", the first result (for me) was from SAS, then within that result look for details on "SAS Language Features". This shows that `find()` was newly introduced then, with some new abilities compared to `index()`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SAS. This is an old language and there are many not so obvious solutions. Despair not, for more often there is an answer than not!

As for your question: They allow a bit different things, but function in similar fashion when doing a simple thing.

**Index** returns the position of the specified string. [Documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0vxokxhv8lr84n10nrbnzp7gnba.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

**Find** allows you to narrow down the range where you look for. [Documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p00ab6ey29t2i8n1ihel88tqtga9.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give one example, I can not visit you links.